# sql sum duration within start and stop time stamps

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to sum the duration based on the number of minutes one time stamp (start, stop) within an second?

This is what I would want to do.. return the number of minutes an employee was sick during their overtime shift. The records are in segments... a sick exception may not always be within an overtime shift.

All rows would be within the same table `exceptions`.

```
Employee Exception  Start   Stop
Bob      OverTime   09:00   17:00
Jim      OverTime   14:00   16:00
Mark     OverTime   14:00   18:00
Steve    OverTime   10:00   14:00

Employee  Exception  Start  Stop 
Bob      Sick        09:00  09:30
Bob      Sick        14:00  17:00
Jim      Sick        14:00  16:00
```

Results:

```
Bob: 3.5 hours
Jim: 2 hours
```

Comment: Would be nice if you sample include a case where sick wasnt inside overtime shift and desire result for that case, becasue right now is just a simple sum

Comment: what is your sql version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2529e/1)**

```
SELECT O.Employee, 
        CAST(CAST(
                DATEDIFF (
                           minute,
                           CASE WHEN S.Start < O.Start THEN O.Start
                                ELSE S.Start
                           END, 
                           CASE WHEN S.Stop > O.Stop THEN O.Stop
                                ELSE S.Stop
                           END
                         ) * 1.0 / 60 AS decimal (8,1)) as VARCHAR) + ' hours' as hours
 FROM exceptions O  -- Overtime
 JOIN exceptions S  -- Sick
   ON O.Employee = S.Employee 
  AND S.[Start] <= O.[Stop]
  AND S.[Stop] >= O.[Start]  
 WHERE 
      O.Exception  = 'OverTime'
  AND S.Exception  = 'Sick'
```

**NOTE:**

- I didnt include the `sum / group by` so you test first if this are the value your need
- Check this to [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)
- To test ranges outside `Overtime` I add

  - `('Bob', 'Sick', '5:00', '7:00')`  doesn't show up
  - `('Bob', 'Sick', '7:00', '10:00')` only show 1 hour

**OUTPUT**

```
| Employee |     hours |
|----------|-----------|
|      Bob | 0.5 hours |
|      Bob | 1.0 hours |
|      Bob | 3.0 hours |
|      Jim | 2.0 hours |
```

**[EDIT](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2529e/2)** I add the version with `SUM`

```
 SELECT O.Employee, 
        CAST(CAST(
                SUM(DATEDIFF (
                           minute,
                           CASE WHEN S.Start < O.Start THEN O.Start
                                ELSE S.Start
                           END, 
                           CASE WHEN S.Stop > O.Stop THEN O.Stop
                                ELSE S.Stop
                           END
                         ) * 1.0 / 60) AS decimal (8,1)) as VARCHAR) + ' hours' as hours
 FROM exceptions O  -- Overtime
 JOIN exceptions S  -- Sick
   ON O.Employee = S.Employee 
  AND S.[Start] <= O.[Stop]
  AND S.[Stop] >= O.[Start]  
 WHERE 
      O.Exception  = 'OverTime'
  AND S.Exception  = 'Sick'
 GROUP BY O.Employee
```

Comment: Juan! I'm so amazed you took so much of your time to help me out here... I've been at work.. I had issues with your pre-edit version but this one works great. It's very easy to read and you've explained everything so well... I'm a little blow away by how much you helped me... I only have 11/15 rep so I can't up vote you... as soon as I hit 15 you bet I am!

Comment: I just upvote your question. Btw you didnt answer what version you have? because 2012+ is better use `IIF` instead of `CASE`. Yes, writting code without debugging is like doing crossword with a pen. That is why I prepare the fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    Employee,
    SUM(
        DATEDIFF(minute,
            (CASE WHEN SickStart > OvertimeStart THEN SickStart ELSE OvertimeStart END),
            (CASE WHEN SickStop > OvertimeStop THEN OvertimeStop ELSE SickStop END)
    )) / 60.0 [hours]
FROM (  
    SELECT e1.Employee, e1.START SickStart, e1.STOP SickStop,
           e2.START OvertimeStart, e2.STOP OvertimeStop 
    FROM   Exceptions e1
    JOIN   Exceptions e2 ON e1.Employee = e2.Employee
                AND (e1.START BETWEEN e2.START AND e2.STOP 
                OR e1.STOP BETWEEN e2.START AND e2.STOP)
    WHERE  e1.EXCEPTION = 'Sick'
           AND e2.EXCEPTION = 'OverTime'
) AS t
GROUP BY Employee;
```

Comment: I upvote because you tought the `minute / 60` and data range, but check my answer to see a better way to detect ranges overlap. Just want to point you dont need use subquery to calculate the `SUM`. And is easy to read if you use alias like `O, S` instead `e1, e2`

Comment: Jamie, thank you for your response.. I think you and Juan kinda answered my question together... I appreciate you taking time out of your day to help a stranger.